# Using regular expression to rename column value

Tags: python, nsregularexpression

I have a data set which has a column of values like:

```
    df1.iloc[:,0]

    0      data143_2220020_1
    1      data143_2220020_2
    2      data105_2220058_1
    3      data105_2220058_2
    4      data134_2221056_2
```

I only want the values in the median, which are something like `2220020`. I have tried following code:

```
     df1.iloc[:,0] = df1.iloc[:,0].str.extract('data.*_(.*)_.*')
```

However, it only returns `NAN`. I have also tried several other things but none of them work. Could anyone help? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: ``df1.iloc[:, 0].str.split('_').str[1]`` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always in that format you could split it on the underscores and get the middle value:

```py
df1.iloc[:,0] = df1.iloc[:,0].str.split('_').str[1]
```

Comment: Have you run the above code, it will throw error... check !!